# How to prove that the decidable languages are closed against iteration only by enumerators?

Tags: computability, closure-properties, enumeration

We have the $L\in R$, how can we prove that $L^*\in R$ only by enumerators?

I try to use induction, but as I understand I wrong...
I'd like to get any help!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Also, the question sounds very familiar – I believe it has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see how to use induction here.

Let's take as an example $L = \{0,1\}$. Then $L^* = \{\epsilon, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, \ldots\}$. You probably know how to enumerate $L^*$. Same thing works if $L = \{w_0,w_1\}$ for two arbitrary words.

The next step is to handle a language with infinitely many words. Following the earlier convention, I'll just indicate how to solve it for the special in which $L = \mathbb{N}$, and instead of $L^*$ I will use comma-separated sequences. Here is my enumeration:
$$
\epsilon; 1; 2; 1,1; 3; 1,2; 2,1; 1,1,1; 4; \ldots
$$
and so on. See if you can figure out a pattern (or if you don't like my pattern, come up with a different one).

Comment: It's great answer Yuval! Thank you!! But can you explain more about the enumeration (the order of the words)? I think I understand it (the idea), but I'd like to understand more of the order of your enumeration... Thank you!!

Comment: That's your task. There's more than one possible answer.